# How to equip new weapons in GTA 5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

My weapon wheel is full and I bought new weapon how do i equip it?I tried to look in inventory but there is just glasses hats and masks!

Answer (score 3):

When you are on the weapon wheel, you can see that each 'spoke' of the wheel is a different weapon type.

[image: Weapon Selection Wheel]

You can see in the example above, currently selected is `Carbine Rifle < 2/2 >`

When you are on a specific spoke, you can toggle between different weapons (in the example, there are 2) using:

PC:   Mousewheel
Xbox: D-Pad
PS4:  D-Pad / Touchpad